# Run seed database

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, database-migration

How do I run the seed method in .NET Core?

This is my onModelBuilding method:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    Users user = new Users
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
        UserName = "system@admin.com",
        Email = "system@admin.com",
        FirstName = "System",
        LastName = "Administrator",
        CreatedOn = DateTime.Now,
        UpdatedOn = DateTime.Now
    };
    PasswordHasher<Users> passwordHasher = new PasswordHasher<Users>();
    user.PasswordHash = passwordHasher.HashPassword(user, "P@ssw0rd");

    modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(schema: DatabaseGlobals.SchemaName);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Users>().HasData(
        user    
    );
    modelBuilder.Entity<UserRoles>().HasKey(k=>new { k.UserId, k.RoleId});
    modelBuilder.Entity<Applications>();
    modelBuilder.Entity<Roles>();
    modelBuilder.Entity<EventLogs>();
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

I tried to run Update-database but then it didn't do anything because my tables were already created.

My model sits in a ClassLibrary and I don't have a Startup.cs file

Comment: This seems more like an entity framework core question

Comment: I'm not sure. In ASP.NET MVC 5, the seed would run after the table creation. But i'm not sure how it works here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add-migration anyname

update-database
```